# Vote based approval system in DBMS

Tags: postgresql, database-design, query

I try to create a system to auto approve proposed posts by popular vote. I am currently evaluating what portions of this I can do within the DBMS and if it is sensible. I use PostgreSQL and I can go up to the newest version if that helps me.

My database structure would look somwhat like this:

```
CREATE TYPE state AS ENUM ('write', 'vote');

CREATE TABLE post
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT post_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(100),
  state state
);

CREATE TABLE proposal
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT proposal_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT proposal_post_fkey REFERENCES post,
  text TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE accepted
(
  id SERIAL NOT NULL CONSTRAINT accepted_pkey PRIMARY KEY,
  post_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT accepted_post_fkey REFERENCES post,
  text TEXT
);

CREATE TABLE vote
(
  proposal_id INTEGER CONSTRAINT vote_proposal_fkey REFERENCES proposal,
  user_id INTEGER,
  PRIMARY KEY(proposal_id, user_ID)
);
```

[Here you can find a SQLFiddle for that layout](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/dfc88/1)

My goal is now to build on or more queries to copy the proposal to accepted and set the state to write according to these rules:

1. If the number of votes for a proposal is more higher than a threshold n
2. If there is exactly one proposal with the highest vote count

My question is now whether this can sensibly be done within PostgreSQL or should be done outside and also if you could point me into the right direction for the queries. Also I wonder if it would make sense to track the votes on a column on the proposal to save on the `JOIN` and `COUNT()`

Comment: Why do you think you need a separate `accepted` table?

Comment: My thought is that it will help with write locks as there is no direct way to insert into this table. So if I move a lot of rows into that table I won't lock out others.